# my react function hook not returning data state inside a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my function hook:

```
const useSignIn = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const signUp = useCallback(async ({ email, password, confirmPassword }) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await api.post("/auth/sign_up/", {
        email,
        password,
        password_confirmation: confirmPassword,
      });
      setData(response.data);
      console.log("signUp response", response.data);
    } catch (error) { 
      if (
        error.response &&
        error.response.data &&
        error.response.data.errors &&
        error.response.data.errors.email
      ) {
        setError(error.response.data.errors.email[0]);
      } else setError("Something went wrong");
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);
  return { loading, signUp, error, data };
};
```

then i use it in my react hook component like this:

```
  const { signUp, error: signUpError, loading, data } = useSignUp();

  const onSubmit = async ({
    email,
    password,
    confirmPassword,
  }: InitialValues) => {
    await signUp({ email, password, confirmPassword });
    console.log("data 0 ", data);
```

but what happens after signUp is resolved is that data is null? why is it that data is null? my log has data in it but just not on my component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `data` you're looking at (the one you've logged) is the one from the *previous* render.

Instead, use `data` when rendering (when `loading` isn't `true`) and your component will be called to re-render when `data` changes — whereupon it will get a new copy of `data` from `useSignup`.

Comment: ah so i should useEffect on my component, Thanks!

Comment: @gpbaculio - Why?

Comment: when u said "from the previous render" i realize i would have to do useEffect on data and it works now

Comment: @gpbaculio - But your component will be called to re-render anyway, without any need for `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

You're never actually setting the data equal to SignUp, you're setting the data with your useState hook (setData) but never assign it to SignUp. You need a return function instead, or after the useState hook, such as `return (response.data)` .